# Issues with video path

Tags: testing, configuration, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

TestCafe doesn't recognize ${TEST} for video path.

I'm trying to implement test recording for failed tests in order to see how we could replicate the appeared problem, but the video path isn't recognized even though a similar path pattern works for screenshots.

[According to the documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/screenshots-and-videos.html), this should work but the following warning is displayed:

```
Warnings (1):

The "${TEST}" path pattern placeholder cannot be applied to the recorded video.

The placeholder was replaced with an empty string.
```

I created TestRunner.js as shown in https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html. Then I added

```
if(runnerOptions.takeVideo === true && runInParallel === 1) {
    runner.video(reports.videoPath, {
        singleFile: true,
        failedOnly: true,
        pathPattern: store + '-' + env + '/${TEST}/${DATE}_${TIME}/${USERAGENT}'
    })
}

return runner
    .src(tests)
    .browsers(config.browsers)
    .screenshots(reports.screenshotPath, runnerOptions.takeScreenshots,
         store + '-' + env + '/${TEST}/${DATE}_${TIME}/${RUN_ID}/${USERAGENT}/step-${FILE_INDEX}')
    .concurrency(runInParallel)
    .run(runnerOptions.run);
```

As I said screenshots work fine, but videos don't.

Comment: How are you defining the path pattern? ${TEST} seems to be working on my end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3455), specifying `singleFile: true` is the cause. When saving all the failed tests into one recording, the path pattern can't use a single test or fixture identifier to name the file.

The following pattern placeholders resolve to an empty string with a single file:

- ${TEST_ID}
- ${TEST_INDEX}
- ${FIXTURE}
- ${TEST}
- ${TEST_ID}

The [documentation for the path patterns](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/screenshots-and-videos.html#video-custom-path-pattern) does mention this restriction for single files, but only in reference to ${TEST_ID} and not the other placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the scenario and it works without any "path pattern" issues under Windows 10:

```
testcafe chrome test.js --video artifacts/videos --video-options pathPattern=${TEST}.mp4
```

Would you please clarify how you specified the `pathPattern` [video option](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/screenshots-and-videos.html#basic-video-options)? In addition, please provide your environment details.